# After update dataTable loose its default sort order

Tags: primefaces

Hi I have a dataTable where I have kept sortBy attribute to my id and sorting Order is descending.

When a click my commandButton which do ajax call and update the dataTable, my datatable loose its default sort order. Even it doesn't change its icon.

How can I update the table without affecting current sorting order or default sorting order.

Comment: Please post your code.